# Can not login through ssh on my machine

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, chroot

Whenever I add a user to the "sftp" group so I can use chroot I can no longer connect through SSH and it says: "**Could not chdir to home directory /home/sftp_user: No such file or directory**" and "**This service allows sftp connections only**". If I set the owner of **/home/sftp_user** to **sftp_user** then I can login but chroot does not work anymore. How can I fix this so I will be able to SSH and use chroot(only on SFTP not SSH) as well?

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details_

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding no
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin yes".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

Match Group sftp
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant lines from the sshd configuration file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I dont think what you are asking is possible.

From the sshd_config manual:

```
 ChrootDirectory
         Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after
         authentication.  At session startup sshd(8) checks that all
         components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are
         not writable by any other user or group.  After the chroot,
         sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home
         directory.
```

So, for the chroot to work the directory must be root owned. This is why it doesn't work when you change the owner of /home/sftp_user.

On the other hand, when the owner is correct chroot works but you are trying to access a path (your home directory) that is outside the chroot. If you want this to work you will need to create the home folder inside the chroot. So if you get chrooted to /home/sftp_user you will need to create /home/sftp_user/home/sftp_user.

When connecting there is no way sshd can tell if you want to do "ssh" or "sftp". So you will need to differentiate using some other method. Maybe a sftp specific account or something.

Comment: Yeah I figured I had to use different accounts. :( Thank you anyway.